# How to find the immediate nearest value in java

Tags: java

I am doing insert after operation automation, according to  my case, whenever insert after the case came.. I want to get the nearest minimum value and select that value... here i am fetching from my gui to take the all sequenceNo values and store it in array

```
 List<Integer> getSequenceNo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int cellIndex = 14;cellIndex < pbp_insert_grid_cells.size();cellIndex+=17)  //  
            {

                rowSequenceNo = pbp_insert_grid_cells.get(cellIndex).getText();

                String[] splitvalue=rowSequenceNo.split("\\.");
                int guiSequenceNo=Integer.parseInt(splitvalue[0]);
            getSequenceNo.add(guiSequenceNo); //1
            }


getSequenceNo contains [1,2,3,1.5,5,6,7,4,12,13,1.75,4.5]
```

here my current sequenceNo is 4.5, and i need to get 4 value from the array list... that means nearest minimum value

Comment: How does this question apply to QA or automated testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] seq = new String[]{"1","2","3","1.5","5","6","7","4","12","13","1.75","4.5"};

    String baseS = "4.5";
    double baseD = Double.parseDouble(baseS);
    double candidateD = 1;
    for(String item: seq){
        double itemD = Double.parseDouble(item);
        if(itemD < baseD && itemD > candidateD){
            candidateD = itemD;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(candidateD));
}
```

if you need to take just the nearest value (not necessarily minimal one) then the code would look much more complex:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] seq = new String[]{"1","2","3","1.5","5","6","7","4","12","13","1.75","4.5"};
    List<Double> seqD = new ArrayList<>();
    // Convert to list of doubles
    for(String item: seq){
        seqD.add(Double.parseDouble(item));
    }
    // Sort list
    seqD.sort(new Comparator<Double>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
            double res = o2.doubleValue() - o1.doubleValue();
            if(res < 0){
                return 1;
            }else if (res > 0){
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
    // Take some base value
    String base = "1.5";
    int baseIndex = seqD.indexOf(Double.valueOf(base));
    if(baseIndex >= 0){
        Double closest = null;
        int rightIndex = baseIndex;
        int leftIndex = baseIndex;
        // Calclulate index of the nearest "right" value that is not equal to base value 
        while (rightIndex < seqD.size() - 1 && seqD.get(rightIndex).equals(Double.valueOf(base))){
            rightIndex++;
        }
        // Calculate index of the nearest "left" value that is not equal to base value
        while (leftIndex > 0 && seqD.get(leftIndex).equals(Double.valueOf(base))){
            leftIndex--;
        }
        // Handle corner cases when there is no left or right value (take either first or last element as "base")
        if(leftIndex == baseIndex){
            closest = seqD.get(rightIndex);
        }else if(rightIndex == baseIndex){
            closest = seqD.get(leftIndex);
        }else{
            // Handle regualr situation when there are some left and right values
            closest = Math.abs(seqD.get(rightIndex)-seqD.get(baseIndex)) < Math.abs(seqD.get(leftIndex) - seqD.get(baseIndex)) ? seqD.get(rightIndex) : seqD.get(leftIndex);
        }
        System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(closest.doubleValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain the working of the code... thanks

Comment: here  I am not able to understand.. it will get everytime for  the  nearest smaller value..

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what you asked *I want to get the nearest minimum value and select that value*